# How are dimensions converted in multiplication and division?

Tags: tex-core, dimension-expressions

In the *TeXbook* it is said (page 118):

> Multiplication and division are possible too, but only by integers. ... Dimension values are integer multiples of sp (scaled points).

Example 1. Result is `25pt minus -150pt`. Why is the multiplicand converted to the same dimension as the multiplier?

```
\dimen1=25pt
\skip2=1sp minus -6sp
\multiply\skip2 by \dimen1
\showthe\skip2

> 25.0pt minus -150.0pt
```

Example 2. The result is `25sp minus -150sp`. Everything looks good.

```
\dimen1=25sp
\skip2=1sp minus -6sp
\multiply\skip2 by \dimen1
\showthe\skip2

> 0.00038pt minus -0.00229pt
```

Example 3. The result is `25sp minus -150sp`. Why is the multiplier converted to the same dimension as the multiplicand?

```
\count1=25
\skip2=1sp minus -6sp
\multiply\skip2 by \count1
\showthe\skip2

> 0.00038pt minus -0.00229pt
```

Comment: @egreg: I think they are in the same category in *TeXbook*. Aren't they anologous?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a convention that even register (except count) numbers smaller than ten are free registers for *local* assignments, whereas odd numbers should only be used for *global* assignments. Mixing local and global assignments can cause memory trouble. Therefore I have multiplied the register numbers by two to get register numbers for local assignments. The first ten count registers have a special meaning (page number, ...). A free count register for local assignments is count register 255 (`\dimen@`).

TeX stores length values as integer numbers with implicit unit `sp`. 2<sup>16</sup> sp are 1 pt. When TeX expects a number and gets a length value, then this integer number is used.

Commented examples:

**Example 1:**

```
\dimen2=25pt
% 25pt = 25 * 65536sp = 1638400sp
\showthe\numexpr\dimen2\relax % \edef\x{\number\dimen2}\show\x
> 1638400

\skip4=1sp minus -6sp
\multiply\skip4 by \dimen2
% (1sp minus -6sp) * 1638400 = 1638400sp minus -9830400sp
% = 25pt minus -150pt
\showthe\skip4

> 25.0pt minus -150.0pt
```

**Example 2:**

```
\dimen2=25sp
\skip4=1sp minus -6sp
\multiply\skip4 by \dimen2
% (1sp minus -6sp) * 25 = 25sp minus -150sp
\showthe\skip4

> 0.00038pt minus -0.00229pt
```

**Example 3:**

```
\count255=25
\skip4=1sp minus -6sp
\multiply\skip4 by \count255
% (1sp minus -6sp) * 25 = 25sp minus -150sp
\showthe\skip4

> 0.00038pt minus -0.00229pt
```